# Output JSON data using Jquery GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I'm using Jquery GET to fetch some JSON data that looks like this:

```
{
    "list": {
        "meta": {
            "type": "resource-list",
            "start": 0,
            "count": 1
        },
        "resources": [
            {
                "resource": {
                    "classname": "Quote",
                    "fields": {
                        "change": "-0.400002",
                        "chg_percent": "-1.200485",
                        "day_high": "33.779999",
                        "day_low": "32.549999",
                        "issuer_name": "PayPal Holdings, Inc.",
                        "issuer_name_lang": "PayPal Holdings, Inc.",
                        "name": "PYPL",
                        "price": "32.919998",
                        "symbol": "PYPL",
                        "ts": "1442606400",
                        "type": "equity",
                        "utctime": "2015-09-18T20:00:00+0000",
                        "volume": "16488139",
                        "year_high": "42.550000",
                        "year_low": "30.000000"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I would like to get the value of `day_high`. Using Jquery I do:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "http://****.com",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        var x = JSON.stringify(data.list.resource.change);
       $("p.name").append(x);
       console.log(x.change);
    }
});
```

In my console I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'change' of undefined
```

I also tried an array approach like `data.list.resource[0].change` But this outputs:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Comment: Why are you using `JSON.stringify` here? Resulted data is already in json format.

Comment: JSON.stringify makes it a string, 'resources.resource', not 'resource'

Comment: @Lazarev Alexandr I was getting [object object] in my console. Apparently Jquery turns the data in to an object. I cant do anything with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the variable x cannot be interpreted as JSON with your console logging statement because `JSON.stringify` converts it to a string. Second, it looks like you have your path mixed up. It should be `data.list.resources[0].resource.fields.change`.

Comment: I get `undefined` no matter how I write it with or without JSON.stringify

Comment: Oh wait you changed it , now it works, thank you very much:)

Comment: Yes JSON.stringify was not necessary

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var x = JSON.stringify(data.list.resources[0].resource.fields.change);
```

The error was with your path.